# FileOutputStream Exception EACCES Permission Denied

Tags: android, permissions, fileoutputstream, storage-access-framework

I tryed many solutions in the forum but they do not seem to work. I need to create a pdf in my phone (Environment.getExternalStorageState() +File.separator +"Try" +File.separator +"FirstPdf.pdf";) but i have an exception. 
I use `verifyStoragePermissions(this)` and 
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in the manifest.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it

Comment: on which device are you working?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` to `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +File.separator +"Try" +File.separator +"FirstPdf.pdf");\
// here your logic for write pdf file
```

**Note:**

you are trying `getExternalStorageState()` and it will
 `Returns the current state of the primary shared/external storage media`.

**Refer:** [External storage state](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState())